# Errors when using OFF_HEAP Storage with Spark 1.4.0 and Tachyon 0.6.4

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, alluxio

I am trying to persist my RDD using off heap storage on spark 1.4.0 and tachyon 0.6.4 doing it like this :

```
val a = sqlContext.parquetFile("a1.parquet")
a.persist(org.apache.spark.storage.StorageLevel.OFF_HEAP)
a.count()
```

Afterwards I am getting the following exception.

Any ideas on that?

```
15/06/16 10:14:53 INFO : Tachyon client (version 0.6.4) is trying to connect master @ localhost/127.0.0.1:19998
15/06/16 10:14:53 INFO : User registered at the master localhost/127.0.0.1:19998 got UserId 3
15/06/16 10:14:53 INFO TachyonBlockManager: Created tachyon directory at /tmp_spark_tachyon/spark-6b2512ab-7bb8-47ca-b6e2-8023d3d7f7dc/driver/spark-tachyon-20150616101453-ded3
15/06/16 10:14:53 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added rdd_10_3 on ExternalBlockStore on localhost:33548 (size: 0.0 B)
15/06/16 10:14:53 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added rdd_10_1 on ExternalBlockStore on localhost:33548 (size: 0.0 B)
15/06/16 10:14:53 ERROR TransportRequestHandler: Error while invoking RpcHandler#receive() on RPC id 5710423667942934352
org.apache.spark.storage.BlockNotFoundException: Block rdd_10_3 not found
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.getBlockData(BlockManager.scala:306)
    at org.apache.spark.network.netty.NettyBlockRpcServer$$anonfun$2.apply(NettyBlockRpcServer.scala:57)
    at org.apache.spark.network.netty.NettyBlockRpcServer$$anonfun$2.apply(NettyBlockRpcServer.scala:57)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:108)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.map(ArrayOps.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.network.netty.NettyBlockRpcServer.receive(NettyBlockRpcServer.scala:57)
    at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportRequestHandler.processRpcRequest(TransportRequestHandler.java:114)
    at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportRequestHandler.handle(TransportRequestHandler.java:87)
    at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportChannelHandler.channelRead0(TransportChannelHandler.java:101)
    at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportChannelHandler.channelRead0(TransportChannelHandler.java:51)
    at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:105)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:333)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:319)
    at io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelRead(IdleStateHandler.java:254)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:333)
```

I have also tried the same with the text file and I was able to persist it in tachyon. The problem is with persisting DataFrame originally read from parquet.

Comment: I think, you added these method after the build or may be, There is some build error. Try with rebuild.

Comment: I have not added them by myself. Spark is trying to call them during persisting the RDD to tachyon

Comment: I have no idea about tachyon. You first check the dependency version, is it compatible or not, or some missing dependencies.

Comment: Is it possible for you to post your code here?

Comment: Are you sure this is related to off-heap allocation? In that case, may be related to serialization issues. Interested in code as well.

Comment: I have added the code. Btw it is working with text files, and is failing with parquet...

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a related bug report: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-10314

Since there seems to be a pull request for this, there might be a chance to soon get a fix for this.

From this thread, https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/tachyon-users/xb8zwqIjIa4, it looks like Spark is using TRY_CACHE mode to write to Tachyon so the data seems to get lost when evicted from the cache.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is fixed now. 
I can confirm this working now with Spark 1.5 and Tachyon 0.7